# I cannot create a pandas data frame with exec() function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using exec() function in python to dynamically name dataframes (different name for each run of the for loop). This is my code:

```
exec(inputs[5] + " = pd.DataFrame(index=range(a), columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

I guess that it could be the issue of exec function somehow not fetching pandas package, even though I have already imported it with

```
import pandas as pd
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: "I am using exec() function in python to dynamically name dataframes (different name for each run of the for loop)." don't do that.

Comment: Dynamically creating variables will only work in the global scope, but will not work in local scopes. However, this error shouldn't be happening in this case, unless you aren't showing us something. Please provide a [mcve]. But seriously, you shouldn't be doing this *to begin with*

Answer (score 1):

When I tried the same code, it worked.

1. using exec function.

```
import pandas as pd
inputs = "df"
exec(inputs + " = pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])")

print(df.shape)
```

2. using eval function.

```
df = eval(" pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])")
print(df.shape)
```

Just make sure the import is before the exec/eval func. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: you can do something like 
`inputs[5] = eval("pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])")`